# timeout functionality for worker in a pool

Tags: php, pthreads

What is the best solution to build a timeout functionality for workers of a pool using php pthreads library?

My idea is to kill worker from inside after N seconds, but can be also done from external.

One possibility can be a thread that kill other threads?

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

When your worker threads are idle, they are likely to be waiting for more work in `pthread_cond_wait()`.

So, to implement a timeout, you can just change that to `pthread_cond_timedwait()`, and have the thread unlock the mutex and exit if the timeout expires.

Comment: Tnx @caf . There is a misunderstanding I think . I mean that I need to build a timeout for active workers, not for the idle ones.

Comment: @cleaversdev: That's a lot more tricky to get right, because you need to ensure you don't leave shared state inconsistent.  The best way is probably to have the worker threads themselves regularly check for the timeout - that way, they can clean up any half-finished work and exit cleanly.